# Xap.require in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to work with [this tutorial](https://www.aridhia.com/blog/interactively-visualising-dicom-volumes-and-header-data/). I'm confused because in the very first line there is this code

```
xap.require('oro.dicom','oro.nifti')
```

but I cannot find any function called `xap.require` online or with `??`. It seems like this is related to software developement. Does anyone have idea what this is for?

Comment: It looks like part of a preloaded package that only exists on Aridhia's AnalytiXagility platform

Answer (score 0):

It would appear this is a peculiarity of `ANALYTIXAGILITY`. My guess is that they have their own package for integrating the R console into their platform.